# Where is data written in a MySQL Cluster?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a MySQL Cluster.

It has, 2 mysqld, 2 data nodes and 1 management nodes.

My question is, when a insert query is made. Where is the data stored? Is it supposed to be stored in the mysqld and replicated into the data nodes. Or all storage is handled by the data nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Cluster stores data in the Data Nodes (NDB storage engine). 
The MySQL Server converts SQL to a native protocol and sends the request to the data nodes.

More explanations can be found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-basics.html

Regarding data related to disk tables, check out the post on MySQL Cluster Disk Data:
http://www.severalnines.com/blog

Best regards,
Vinay